# Definition of $t^{\frown}a$ in Jech: Set theory

Tags: notation, set-theory

I am reading about the consistency of Borel's conjecture in Jech's Set theory, and I can't figure out what
$$
t^{\frown}a
$$
means.

It can be found on p. 565 in Jech's [Set Theory 3rd Millennium Edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CZb-CAAAQBAJ) on line 3.

Comment: You probably shouldn't read Jech's later chapters if you're not already familiar with these concepts.

Comment: There is also a notation index at the end, Jech is very neat this way.

Comment: I have tried looking through the index, but couldn't find anything

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in Kunen's set theory

Comment: It's usually an extension of some tree element $t$ by a $a$, e.g. by concatenation of strings or sequences.